# Best practices for saving model changes only when client sends Save Request while also maintaining session context?

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a flask app where clients are constantly make changes on an object in the model in the DB. Then when the client explicitly sends a "Save" request, the object's new state should be saved to the DB. If the client did not send a "Save" request", I'd like all field changes to be discarded and the object state to be reverted to original state before changes so the next load of the object would be in its original state.

The problem is that I need to be saving even unsaved changes on an object to the DB to provide session context to the next request from the client. **Future requests in the session need the latest state of the object.** But I am effectively losing the original state of the object completely with this approach.

Some example below

```
#models.py - saves an object in the  dashboard field

class Dash(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.INTEGER, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    dashboard = db.Column(db.PickleType(),nullable=True)
```

And in my routes I have the following method that updates a certain attribute in the object:

```
#routes.py

class setInputAPI(Resource):
    def post(self):
        dash = getdash() #gets latest DB object

        dash.value = request.json['new_val'] #changes an object attribute 

        updateDB(dash) #update db with new object so future requests have context
        return {'message':'success'}

#Helper functions
def getdash():
    dash_id = request.json['dash_id']
    dash = Dash.query.get_or_404(dash_id).dashboard
    return dash

def updateDB(dash):
    dash_id = request.json['dash_id']
    db.session.query(Dash).filter(Dash.id == dash_id).update({'dashboard': dash})
    db.session.commit()
```

When the above `setInputAPI` request is sent, my DB state will be updated to reflect the client's changes without the client even sending a Save request. So I have lost all original data and if the client were to reload this object in a future session they would see their changed object instead of the last saved one.

A potential solution could be to create a duplicate table that just tracks the last saved state of the object and loads that instead.

So I could have 2 tables - one to track `last_saved` state and another to track `current_unsaved` state.

But I have to imagine there must be a better way to do this as this seems hacky?

Comment: An option might be to store the pending changes [on the session](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#sessions) and only modify the database when the user saves.

Comment: Interesting. Is the session object multi-thread/multi-process safe though?

Comment: Yeh, default implementation stores on the client. Don’t store anything sensitive in there.

Comment: 1. You can have multiple states of the data like "draft", "Saved". OR 2.  Store the intermediate states in your browser local storage?